# Reverb and Tone effects to Media player : android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, multimedia

I am developing application similar to Music Player.
I am using Mediaplayer in android.
I am unable get those effects please help me on this ....
Actually I want to create an equalizer from which I can change the reverb & tone values of music, which MediaPlayer is playing.But I am not getting any way to do it.

Platform : Android

Waiting for response.....

Comment: What specifically is the problem? What does your code for adding and enabling the effects look like? Do you get any errors in the logcat output?

Comment: @Michael Actually I want to create an equalizer from which I can change the reverb & tone values of music, which MediaPlayer is playing.But I am not getting any way to do it.

Comment: Equalization and reverb are two different things. If you want reverb you should use the `EnvironmentalReverb` effect, not the `Equalizer` effect.

Comment: @ Michael I have tried with EnvironmentalReverb and PresetReverb and even though I have tried Android NDK native audio app but I am not able to set the reverb effect.......Please help me I am stuck at this point ...

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in 2 ways

One before creating the media player instance you can attach them by creating spepcifc set of profiles
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#attachAuxEffect(int)

After creating mediaplayer, you can still create new aux and you need give mediaplayer's id with it. You need to set session id for mediaplayer before doing setsource. - setAudioSessionId

Krishna

Comment: Hello Krishna, I am using this way :PresetReverb mReverb = new PresetReverb(1, mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
if (progress < 1)
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_NONE);
else if (progress < 10)
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_SMALLROOM);
else if (progress < 20)
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_PLATE);
else if (progress < 40)
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_MEDIUMROOM);
else if (progress < 60)
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_MEDIUMHALL);
else if (progress < 80)
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);
else if (progress < 101)

Comment: mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
mReverb.setEnabled(true);
int currentPosition = affimationPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
mediaPlayer.attachAuxEffect(mReverb.getId());
mediaPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
Please correct me, where I am making mistake ?

Comment: The another way in which I have tried :eReverb = new EnvironmentalReverb(0,mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
eReverb.setDecayHFRatio((short) 1000);
eReverb.setDecayTime(progress * 10);
eReverb.setDensity((short) 1000);
eReverb.setDiffusion((short) (progress * 10));
eReverb.setReverbLevel((short) (progress * 10));
eReverb.setReverbDelay((progress * 10));
eReverb.setReflectionsLevel((short) (progress * 10));
eReverb.setRoomHFLevel((short) (progress * 10));
eReverb.setRoomLevel((short) (progress * 10));
eReverb.setReflectionsDelay(progress * 10);

Comment: eReverb.setEnabled(true);
int currentPosition =
mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
mediaPlayer.attachAuxEffect(eReverb.getId());
mediaPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
mediaPlayer.seekTo(current Position); Please help me on this I am stuck at this point and my whole project is depended on this thing. thanks in advance.....